# can I use BytesField in a proto-datasource entity

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore.
I want to save an image related to my entity. Searching revealed that there is indeed a BytesField property type that can be used for this purpose.
I need to know if it is possible to use BytesField in the endpoits-proto-datastore, and if yes how?
Secondly, is this the best way to implement it? or there is a better alternative?

thanks,

Comment: Yes it's possible, no it's not the best thing to use. Use Google Cloud Datastore direct upload.